# what is issue with ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've compiled android-ics-4.0.3. But when I'm trying to boot it on device, it stuck and in logcat I got the following message:

```
E/Netd    ( 1375): Unable to create netlink socket: Protocol not supported
E/Netd    ( 1375): Unable to open quota2 logging socket
E/Netd    ( 1375): Unable to start DnsProxyListener (Protocol not supported)
E/SocketListener( 1375): Obtaining file descriptor socket 'dnsproxyd' failed: Protocol not supported
F/libc    ( 1378): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00008c8c (code=2)
```

I'm unable to find what is the problem. Please help me to resolve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: CONFIG_QUOTA_NETLINK_INTERFACE is off in the kernel?